# Android device not showing on adb anymore

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

Hello stackoverflow mighty community,

**Please help !**

I have a Datalogic DL-AXIST (http://www.datalogic.com/eng/products/automatic-data-capture/mobile-computers/dl-axist-pd-702.html) which is an android device but i guess the company fiddled a bit with its core. Also I have a windows 7 toshiba pc.
Anyway my concern is that it is not showing on the adb devices chooser.
Here is what i've tried so far:

I'm using Eclipse IDE, my SDK is up to date and i can test my application on all the other devices i tried so far.
The datalogic device has Android 4.1.1, driver is correctly installed on my pc i'm sure, enabled developer options.
I tried connecting it as MTP and PTP but will not work, there is also a CD-ROM installer connection which i tried as well, followed through the installation on my pc but still does not work.

It gets even stranger, when i used the third pc connection type and installed the device with its own adb on pc, i even copied those adb files in that folder and pasted them my eclipse's own adb. **This worked !** my device was recognized but it changed for a reason i do not know.

I tried uninstalling the device driver and re-installing it from windows device manager, tried rebooting device and restarting eclipse and pc.

I really need some help because making this device work will greatly benefit my work.

Thanks !

Comment: adb restart might help

Answer (score 0):

This is genuine issue which may come frequently,but the soln is simple you may try these steps:
step 1;
try swictching developer options on and off
if the above dont works then go to device manager in your pc check portables devices select device and update driver software-->browse my comp-->let me pick list of device drivers-->select android as in option or MTP

if your device dont show in portable devices just update the device which comes in portable devices list trust me it works all time

try to do this once

**1. Check if authorized:**

\platform-tools>adb devices List of devices attached 4df798d76f98cf6d unauthorized

**2. Revoke USB Debugging on phone**

If the device is shown as unauthorized, go to the developer options on the phone and click "Revoke USB debugging authorization" (tested with JellyBean & Samsung GalaxyIII).

Restart ADB Server:
Then restarted adb server

adb kill-server adb start-server

**4. Reconnect the device**

The device will ask if you are agree to connect the computer id. You need to confirm it.

Now Check the device
It is now authorized!

adb devices \platform-tools>adb devices List of devices attached 4df798d76f98cf6d device

Comment: Well i too have worked with datalogic devices once we upgrade the device software it works for me.

Comment: i have removed it @tanmeet

Comment: @tanmeet In my adb devices accessed from cmd it shows nothing even with my datalogic plugged, plus under developer options there is no "Revoke USB debugging authorization", i think the company removed it if that's possible... got any other solution ?