# ADB not recognizing device anymore

Tags: android, eclipse, windows, adb

I have already asked about this problem, and still haven't found the solution but i got more leads, so i'll try to explain it as quick as possible:

I have a windows 7 64-bit laptop, using eclipse platform and I want to test my app on DataLogic DL_AXIST android 4.1.1 device.

- This android device shows on all other pcs and adb but mine.
- The first time this device's driver was installed on my pc, my adb showed it but not anymore for unknown reason.
- Device is connected as MTP, driver installed correctly, I tried all other pc connections available **-->** it shows in my computer but not on adb!!!
- I even created adb_usb.ini file in .android folder and added HEX hardware ID of device and still doesn't work.
- Debugging mode on device is running, i have restarted ADB as well.

Please if anyone knows another method do tell me i'm losing my mind

Comment: Can you test other USB ports, can you also test that the adb worked with any other Android device as well? Also, can you check that a prompt appeared on your Android device, and that you "trusted this new computer" to work with the android device?

Comment: Yes i have tested other ports and the adb works with other android devices, but can you tell me how to prompt that message again ? you are right the problem may be caused by that. But when i branch this device the message does not show again. What to do ? @Bonatti

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android device not showing on adb anymore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38325211/android-device-not-showing-on-adb-anymore)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ADB requires that the USB debugging tool be paired with the Computer.

In Config -> Developer Options, uncheck the "USB debug mode", unplug the USB cable, check "USB debug mode" again, then replug the USB cable, a prompt stating "Do you trust this XY:AB:CD:EF device" and allow it for a new connection.

#### edit

If the prompt for pairing was not triggered, revoke all debbuging permissions (in the same screen), and redo the activation process.

I am sorry that, my devices are in another non-english language, so I do not know the way its probably spelt in english.

Comment: this is not a problem with authorization. also RSA key fingerprint has nothing to do with MAC address.

Comment: SOLVED !! 
By deleting the adbkeys file found in C:\Users[Username].android folder the permission dialog appeared on my device.